# How to detect if FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON has been set inside an Activity only?

Tags: android

My question is with reference to the following link:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

I am using APKs and thus ASM to read through the classes.
I have also gone through ASM Guide by Eric Bruneton.

TraceClassVisitor is the closest I found something close enough to accomplish what I am trying to do.
But it is not good enough.

I have chosen few Android apps from Google PlayStore and am trying to find out if they cause more battery drain than they actually should.........

Using ASM, how do I find out if `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` has been called from inside an Activity only?
If it were a method, I could have just checked if the owner of the method was a class which extends Activity. But the problem here is that `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` will be passed as a parameter by using

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

So how do I detect that FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON is set inside an Activity?
If not I will need to log it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [getWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()) is a method inside Activity. So only Activities(may be dialogs as well) can set the `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag.

Comment: But just checking for the methodName getWindow is not sufficient. The parameter that is passed also needs to be checked right? It needs to be confirmed that the parameter passed is `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`

Comment: Not sure, what you are trying to achieve. if you need to find out if some activity is requesting for SCREEN_ON, you can probably check PowerManager logs, it should print the Process id. Then you can find out if and activity is requesting for screen on.

Comment: @sujith we can use `getActivity().getWindow()` in fragments as well.

Comment: @Choletski Yes, we should be able to use with out any problem.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to check if device screen is on than apply your logic inside this

```
PowerManager powermanager;
powermanager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
if (powermanager.isScreenOn()){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
```