# How do I determine if FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON already has been set?

Tags: android

I lock the screen depending on certain conditions, and release after the conditions that no longer satisfy. Is there a way to check if lock is already On and do not set it again? And by extension, is there any negative effect for setting this lock again even if it is already On?

here is the method to set it On

`

```
        final Activity activity = themedContext.getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {    
                  activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
            });
        }
```

`

and here is a method to set it Off:
`

```
        final Activity activity = themedContext.getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            Log.d("onVideoSizeChanged ", "screenOnLockRelease");
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {   
                 activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
            });
        }
```

`
themedContext - is just the app context

The only related post I found: [How to detect if FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON has been set inside an Activity only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158045/how-to-detect-if-flag-keep-screen-on-has-been-set-inside-an-activity-only)

But when I check the attributes with: 
`WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = getAttributes();`
I can not seems to get flags from it.
I am not very proficient with JAVA yet, so please be explicit with the answer. Thank you forward